Is it possible to create a remap in VsCodeVim that doesn't automatically hit Enter in normal mode?
Is it possible to create a remap in VScodeVim that doesn't automatically hit Enter in normal mode?
The remap that I want to create is:
nnoremap s :

That's from the repository, the plugin implies the enter, for example:
{
      "before": ["<C-n>"],
      "commands": [":nohl"]
},


Info
Vscode version: 1.87.2
OS: Windows 10, 22H2
My config: https://gist.github.com/micaelviana/de57f2757b9196dc96f8f9f234740bc2
VScodeVim repo: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim

That's the rest of the guide
{
  "vim.easymotion": true,
  "vim.incsearch": true,
  "vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
  "vim.useCtrlKeys": true,
  "vim.hlsearch": true,
  "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
      "before": ["j", "j"],
      "after": ["<Esc>"]
    }
  ],
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "d"],
      "after": ["d", "d"]
    },
    {
      "before": ["<C-n>"],
      "commands": [":nohl"]
    },
    {
      "before": ["K"],
      "commands": ["lineBreakInsert"],
      "silent": true
    }
  ],
  "vim.leader": "<space>",
  "vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-a>": false,
    "<C-f>": false
  },

  "// To improve performance",
  "extensions.experimental.affinity": {
    "vscodevim.vim": 1
  }
}

